# Python Regular Expressions Excluding Tags

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have written a script which is posted below, which basically goes to the plain text dictionary website and searches for the entered word and retrieves the definition. The only problem is it returns with the closing paragraph tags aswell, i have messed around with this for ages.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import re
import sys


word = 'Xylophone'
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_'+word[0].lower()+'.html')
html = page.read()

match = re.search(r'<P><B>'+word+'</B>.............(.*)', html)

if match: 
    print match.group(1)
else: print 'not found'
```

This returns the definition with tags. Whats the correct regex syntax here to ignore tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prerequisite: read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) famous topic.

Since it is an html page you are parsing, I'd use a specific tool made for this - an `HTML parser`.

For example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

word = 'Xylophone'
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/v003/wb1913_'+word[0].lower()+'.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print soup.find('b', text=word).parent.text
```

prints:

> Xylophone (n.) An instrument common among the Russians, Poles, and
>   Tartars, consisting of a series of strips of wood or glass graduated
>   in length to the musical scale, resting on belts of straw, and struck
>   with two small hammers. Called in Germany strohfiedel, or straw
>   fiddle.

Comment: agree with alecxe - it is much cleaner way... but just to add (?<p>) makes it non capturing... means it would check for it but would not return it..

Comment: how do i add (?<p>) to the above code? i just keep getting errors with that way

Comment: @user3366103 the code should work without any changes - it gets the definition for the keyword.

Comment: yeah the code posted by alecxe works, but how can i add (?<p>) to the original bit of code as that looks like a more readable method?

Comment: @user3366103 sure, you need to install it first: `pip install beautifulsoup4`.